# Speech-Api daily requests quota counter increses too much after one request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node, google-cloud-speech

As I am aware of the limitations listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits), I need to receive some clarifications on the quota limit.
I'm using the Node.js library to make a simple asynchronous speech-to-text API, using a .raw file which is stored in my bucket.
After the request is done, when checking the [API Manager Traffic](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/quotas), the daily requests counter is increased by 50 to 100 requests.
I am not using any kind of requests libraries or other frameworks. Just the code from the gCloud docs.

```
var file = URL.bucket +  "audio.raw"; //require from upload.
speech.startRecognition(file, config).then((data) => {
    var operation = data[0];

    operation.on('complete', function(transcript) {
        console.log(transcript);
    });
})
```

Comment: How much audio is contained in the file?  In terms of pricing the audio is considered as multiple chunks of 15 seconds each according to this page: https://cloud.google.com/speech/pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the `operation.on` call, which registers a listener for the operation to complete, but continues to poll the service until it does finally finish.

I *think*, based on looking at some code, that you can change the interval at which the service will poll using the `longrunning.initialRetryDelayMillis` setting, which should reduce the number of requests you see in your quota consumption.

Some places to look:

1. Speech client constructor: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/master/packages/speech/src/index.js#L70
2. GAX Speech Client's constructor: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/master/packages/speech/src/v1/speech_client.js#L67
3. Operations client: https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/blob/master/lib/operations_client.js#L74
4. GAX's Operation: https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/blob/master/lib/longrunning.js#L304